# Magento 2.2.8 upgrade - Problem with "Unable to unregister protocol phar" during compile

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.8

First, some background.  I have 6 Magento 2.2.x sites on a development server.  4 of the 6 upgraded just fine.  I used the same standard composer upgrade process on all of them.  They're on a single **apache/php** environment via virtualhosts so they all have the same resources.

On 2 of them, I get this error when trying to compile (edited to remove the domain):

> [Exception]
>   Warning: stream_wrapper_unregister(): Unable to unregister protocol
>   phar:// in [DOCUMENT ROOT PATH]/html/app/bootstrap.php on line 11

I can't seem to get any further information about where the issue actually is.  I've reset the files & database to pre-upgrade state and it compiles fine (one is 2.2.7, the other is 2.2.5) -- but if I repeat the upgrade, then it errors again.

Any information about how to troubleshoot further would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little further digging so far - running compile with the '-vvv' verbose output option I can get the module name on each where it dies.  In both cases those are custom modules that make use of bootstrap.php via n include/require.

The sites that did't have an issue don't have anything making a reference to bootstrap.php anywhere in /app/code/* -- so it would seem something changed between 2.2.7 and 2.2.8 as relates to how that bootstrap.php is used/handled.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. Could you explain how to "modified the custom modules not not require bootstrap.php"?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152389)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end, the road block was 2 custom modules that use the app/bootstrap.php

Between 2.2.7 and 2.2.8 there was a commit to bootstrap.php that only added:

```
`stream_wrapper_unregister('phar');`
```

Phar is enabled (verified with phpinfo(); ) but it doesn't seem to have the stream_wrapper enabled as that doesn't list specifically for Phar, but does list for other extensions, like bzip.  So the Magento 2.2.8 code change just fires off a disable without a check to see if it IS enabled first -- apparently.

For now, we've modified the custom modules not not require bootstrap.php

Comment: Having a similar issue, but the upgrade went fine, but the error happens after the upgrade to 2.2.8 from 2.2.7 - how did you figure out which extension was causing the issue?

Comment: Running the compile with verbose output (the -vvv argument) will show you the trace when it dies and which module it is that causes it.  In our case, only one module on each site was trying to use the functions in bootstrap where the change occurred.  The difference in bootstrap is specifically in the 2.2.8 update where they add the unregister without any checking to see if the stream wrapper is even enabled first.  So to get around it you either have to enable the stream wrapper for phar somehow, or change the code to not need bootstrap.

Comment: I tried using the -vvv during compile, but I didn't see any errors in CLI, but that may be because mine is already installed without issue? I was using php bin/magento setup:di:compile ---vvv But it didn't show anything much at all really.

I also tried php bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv and php bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv and none seemed to look any different than the others as far as information display. It was same as if I didn't use -vvv so not to sure what the issue might be - still looking.